# The measure of the image of a linear map

Tags: measure-theory, linear-transformations, lebesgue-measure, determinant

A somewhat similar question was already asked but I'm trying to prove it a different way. I'm somewhat new to the website so not sure if I should've commented on the old thread or not but here it is. I'm working through measure theory and I'm stuck on the following exercise.

Suppose $T\in\text{GL}_d(\mathbb{R})$. The goal is to prove that for any borelian $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we have $\lambda_d(T(B)) = |\det(T)|\lambda_d(B)$, where $\lambda_d$ is the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. The exercise has four steps:

1. Show there exists $k_T>0$ such that for any borelian $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we have $\lambda_d(T(B))=k_T\lambda_d(B)$.
2. Verify that for $S,T\in\text{GL}_d(\mathbb{R})$, $k_{ST}=k_Sk_T$.
3. Show the result above when $T$ is diagonal, then when $T$ is symmetric and finally, when $T$ is orthogonal.
4. Conclude using the fact that for $T\in\text{GL}_d(\mathbb{R})$, there exists $U$ orthogonal and $S$ symmetric such that $T=US$.

I honestly don't know where to start. Even for the first step I'm kind of lost. Apparently, from linearity I can show this for the unit cube and then it naturally extends to all borelian but I don't understand why this would be true either. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: (1) follows from the (slightly technical) "uniqueness result" concerning Lebesgue measure, which says that if $\mu$ is any locally-finite, translation-invariant measure on the Borel (or Lebesgue) $\sigma$-algebra of $\Bbb{R}^n$, then $\mu$ is a scalar multiple of the Borel measure $\beta_n$ (or the Lebesgue measure $\lambda_n$) (note that by $\beta_n$ I simply mean the restriction of $\lambda_n$ to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra). To apply this theorem, you just have to show that the map $B\mapsto \lambda_d(T(B))$ is a locally-finite translation-invariant measure on the Borel sets.

Comment: What have you tried for (2) and (3)?

Comment: I thought I could restrict to the unit cube $I^n$ and ended up trying to see what $T(I^n)$ looked like. I didn't think about using the uniqueness theorem. I will report back after thinking a bit more about it. Thank you!

Comment: Looking at $T(I^n)$ is a good idea for (3), (or if you let $H = [0,1)^n$ be the half-open unit cube, you may want to look at $T(H)$), because what the uniqueness result says is that $\mu = \mu(H) \cdot \lambda_d$, and in your case, $\mu(H) = \lambda_d(T(H))$ so the scalar multiple is exactly the Lebesgue measure of the image of the standard unit cube (so all you have to do is show this equals $|\det T|$ in a few special cases, and then the general result follows).

Comment: Okay so for (2), I found the following: Let $\mu_{ST}:B\to \lambda_d(S(T(B))$. Then $\mu_{ST}(B) = k_S\lambda_d(T(B)) = k_Sk_T\lambda_d(B) = k_{ST}\lambda_d(B)$. This shows (2). I will use your hint for (3).

Comment: So for (3), I have managed to show it directly for diagonal matrices. Using the fact that if $T$ is real symmetric, $T=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal, and combining this fact with (2), I get that $k_T=k_Pk_Dk_P^{-1} = k_Pk_P^{-1}k_D = k_I k_D = k_D = \det |T|$ using (2) above. I'm stuck on showing the last bit for orthogonal matrices though. I know an orthogonal matrix has determinant $\pm 1$, and that $T^{t} = T^{-1}$. I get that $k_T k_{T^{-1}} = 1$. But $k_T$ has to be positive right, since a measure is positive. Therefore $k_T = 1$, and since $T$ is orthogonal, $|\det T| = 1$, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110504/discussion-between-peek-a-boo-and-saegusa).